# merging two list in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

i am trying to merge two list as below

Let **list 1 contains id,name,age** and **list two contains int,varchar,varchar**

My final out put must be **id int,name varchar,age varchar**

I am tried with out using linq or lamda expression

but i need this execution through it.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two lists (i.e. what do the two lists join on)? Do they both have an `id` column or similar?

Comment: What type of List? List of string that contains those values? List of some custom entities? This question is very vague.

Comment: Your list contains varchar?

Comment: Why the linq is not an option ? Because it is ideal sulotion for your problem

Comment: In fact, reading your question again, it sounds like you're trying to Union the two lists, not merge them. Please be *very* precise when editing your question to explain your requirements.

Comment: If you're very clear about your requirements, you can avoid the downvotes (and get better answers). Please improve your questions by using the ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14873129/edit) feature.

Comment: @all here after i will thanks for your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer assumes that both lists contain `string`s, that the number of items is the same in both lists and that they are already correctly ordered.

```
var result = list1.Select((x, i) => x + " " + list2[i]).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
var result = list1.Zip(list2, (x, y) => x + " " + y).ToList();
```

Sample input:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "id", "name", "age" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "int", "varchar", "varchar" };
```

Output:

```
var result = new List<string> { "id int", "name varchar", "age varchar" };
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Zip`, e.g. (to get matches as Tuples)

```
listOne.Zip(listTwo, Tuple.Create);
```